# I develop an audio player with [clients - service] architectures using "exoplayer" as Playback player

Tags: kotlin, exoplayer, android-music-player, mediacontroller, android-mediasession

#### MediaMusicServies [code](https://github.com/Eng-Ahmed-abu-elBukhari/MaxlerPlayer/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/play/maxler/presentation/exoplayer/MediaPlaybackService.kt)

#### MediaSessionConnection [code](https://github.com/Eng-Ahmed-abu-elBukhari/MaxlerPlayer/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/play/maxler/presentation/exoplayer/MediaSessionConnection.kt)

#### MediaStoreSource [code](https://github.com/Eng-Ahmed-abu-elBukhari/MaxlerPlayer/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/play/maxler/presentation/exoplayer/MediaStoreSource.kt)

#### PlaybackPreparer [code](https://github.com/Eng-Ahmed-abu-elBukhari/MaxlerPlayer/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/play/maxler/presentation/exoplayer/PlaybackPreparer.kt)

#### MusicPlayerEventListener [code](https://github.com/Eng-Ahmed-abu-elBukhari/MaxlerPlayer/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/play/maxler/presentation/exoplayer/playback/MusicPlayerEventListener.kt)

/* when press play button every thing run will and MediaSession connect successfully with playback service when press play button every thing run will and MediaSession connect successfully with playback service but exoplayer can`t playing audio */